# Locking required if Multiple threads are accessing & modifying different values from shared dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, locking, .net-4.5

In a multiple threaded environment (C# .Net 4.5) if the multiple threads are using the same dictionary and simultaneously accessing & modifying the different values from different key location, do I still needs to implement locking mechanism.

I can assure at any point of time no two threads are accessing the values from same key location.

And In the same scenario if I implement the locking, will it affect the performance?

Comment: Use a [concurrent dic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) that will do the locking for you?

Comment: Any modification to the dictionary must be protected by some type of synchronization. Even if the keys are different, and even if you know the key already exists, the documented guarantees of the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class don't ensure thread-safety. Even if in practice, you believe no reallocation of the underlying data structures will occur, you can't rely on that. Use `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` if you don't want to do your own synchronization.